# Amazon SimpleDB PuttAttributes

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am new to both PHP and Amazon SimpleDB. I am trying to figure out how to update values in SimpleDB. I created a signature which returns a value so I believe that is working. When I try to follow Amazon's PutAttribute example, my application breaks. Any hints or ideas of what I could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
$item_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["item_name"]);
$timestamp = gmdate('c');
$secretkey = 'mysecretkey';
$accesskey = 'myaccesskey';

$message = "
https://sdb.amazonaws.com/
?Action=PutAttributes
&Attribute.1.Name=body_type
&Attribute.1.Value=02
&Attribute.1.Replace=true
&AWSAccessKeyId=[my access key]
&DomainName=FILE_LOG_DEV
&ItemName={$item_name}
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&Timestamp={$timestamp}
&Version=2009-04-15
";


$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $message, $secretkey, true));

https://sdb.amazonaws.com/
?Action=PutAttributes
&Attribute.1.Name=body_type
&Attribute.1.Value=02
&Attribute.1.Replace=true
&AWSAccessKeyId=[my access key]
&DomainName=FILE_LOG_DEV
&ItemName=$item_name
&SignatureVersion=2
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA1
&Timestamp=$timestamp
&Version=2009-04-15
&Signature=$signature
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AWS PHP SDK` ([link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/index.html)) that will help you to interact with `Amazon SimpleDB Database Service` in easy and friendly manner. `AWS PHP SDK` will internally manage your creating `signature` and `time stamp`. So you need to only focus on `parameters` pass to your method and `result` what you get from that method. Have a look on [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.SimpleDb.SimpleDbClient.html#_putAttributes). Here it will take an `array` as `argument` and returns `a response Model object`.